# How would I write this as a correct SQLite3 statement within Objective-C

Tags: ios, sqlite

I'm having trouble writing the following statement into my Database Controller class within an IOS project.

```
SELECT * FROM GPSJob WHERE sourceMonitor = '%@' AND positionNumber = %d;
```

I understand the need to use `mysqlite3_open()`, `mysqlite3_prepare_v2()` and `mysqlite_step()` but I cannot for the life of my convert the values given from step into an NSString and a NSNumber!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need something like this:

```
 NSString *querySQL = @"SELECT * FROM GPSJob WHERE sourceMonitor = ? AND positionNumber = ?";
```

Then use the following for String

```
 sqlite3_bind_text(sqlite3_stmt*,int,const char*,int,void(*)(void*));
```

and following for int

```
 sqlite3_bind_int(sqlite3_stmt*, int, int);
```

Comment: Sql Injection Attack.  Use bindings instead.

Comment: What you would use with `sqlite3_prepare_v2()`.  What you are asking for is too broad for this site.